# Row Number In Formula Not Counting When I Drag

Tags: excel, formula

I have the formula below that I'm using to link to a certain sheet and cell in my workbook that contains a graph for each entry. On the sheet I link too, each graph is about 20 cells down from the previous one. I have over a 100 graphs now and it will grow in time so I was trying to use the HYPERLINK formula rather than the Hyperlink button for this. I thought I would be able to just insert the formula in the first row, paste it in the second row with an added 20 cells, highlight the two and drag it down but it will not count in increments of 20.

Is this even possible?

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Trends'!A25","Click To View Trend")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you will have to use some type of concatenation to get the behavior you are after.  To do this, you may want to employ a "helper" column.  For example, put the "numbers" you are after in column `B` -- below you will see that I incremented it by 5.

Now your `HYPERLINK` formula *in cell A1* is written as:

`=HYPERLINK("[Book1]Sheet2!A"& B1,"Click Me for Sheet2, Cell A"&B1)`

(Assuming the workbook is called `Book1`.  Now, I can drag that formula down and it will update "dynamically" to account for the changes in column B.

[image: Picture of Output01]

[image: Picture of Output02]